# Emit event into outside component folder?I have done something but It is not listen to the emite event "feature"?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

[image]

This is my folder structure I need to emit 'feature' event which occurs in the src/component/header/app.component.header.html into src/app.component.html

src/component/header/app.component.header.ts

```
<li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" (click)=" onSelect('recipes')" >Recipes <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" (click)="onSelect('shopping-list')" >Shopping List</a>
    </li

>
```

src/component/header/app.component.header.ts

```
@Output() feature =new EventEmitter<string>();

onSelect(featured:string){

    this.feature.emit(featured);
}
```

src/app.component.html

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-12">
    <app-header (feature)="onNavigation($event)" ></app-header>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: please show your app.component.ts i.e onnavigation function and also try to put breakpoint in chrome dev tools on OnSelect function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the type "String", instead use "string"(all small letters). String (and Number, Boolean, etc.) types refer to non-primitive boxed objects and should never be used. Your code works fine after correcting this.

```
 //Wrong   
 @Output() feature =new EventEmitter<String>();

 //Correct
 @Output() feature =new EventEmitter<string>();
```

Same change in onSelect function.

```
 onSelect(featured:string){
    this.feature.emit(featured);
 }
```

Comment: I have added the code in stackblitz. Seems to work for me. Take a look and check console. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vp4d5o